# Proof Verification: Cauchy Sequences are convergent.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Assume $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it is bounded. By Bolzanno-Weierstrass theorem, there is a convergent sub-sequence $(a_{n_j})$; denote its limit as $a$. Thus we have the following: for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n,m \geq N_1 \implies |a_n-a_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$
and $N_2$ such that
$$n_j \geq N_2 \implies |a_{n_j}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Construct $N$ as follows: $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, thus:
$$|a_n-a|=|a_n-a+a_{n_j}-a_{n_j}|\leq|a_n-a_{n_j}|+|a_{n_j}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon,$$
whenever $n\geq n_j \geq N$.

I think my first two inequalities are correct, but I am not so sure about the last part. Anyone care to check my work?

Comment: Hm, I think, that the construction of $N$ might be unnecessary. This is quite confusing.

Comment: seems fine to me. what generates your lack of certainty?

Comment: @DavidHolden The problem is how $N_2$ is chosen, it should be a condition on $j\geq N_2$, not $n_j\geq N_2$.

Comment: For sub-sequences $n_j \geq j$ (the reason why is quite vague to me, it does seem intuitive though). Thus, $j \geq N_2 \implies n_j \geq N_2$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant ah,yes, i see what you mean

Comment: @Kurome Yes that's right, that's what you need to fix it.  Think about $n_j$ as a function $n:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ and write it in more familiar notation $n(j)$, instead of $n_j$, the function must be strictly increasing $n(j+1)>n(j)$ for all $j$.  That's why $n(j)\geq j$.

Comment: Can I take the condition of the existence of $N$ such that $j \geq N \implies |a_{n_j}-a|<\epsilon$ be the definition of a convergent sub-sequence? My book defined what a sub-sequence is, but never explicitly defined what it means for it to converge. In my head: $n_j \geq N \implies |a_{n_j}-a|<\epsilon$ seems more proper.

Comment: @Kurome Maybe as a warm-up prove that if $a_n\rightarrow L$ and $a_{n_j}$ is any subsequence, then $a_{n_j}\rightarrow L$.  The key step is to use that $j\geq n_j$.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quite using the subscript notation correct.  You don't want to say $n_j\geq N_2$, you want to say $j\geq N_2$.

Comment: ... which means we should switch to $N=\max\{N_1,n_{N_2}\}$

Comment: I think that's my problem, I'm not quite sure what it means for sub-sequences to converge.

Comment: Think through an example, like define $b_j$ by $b_j=a_{n_j}=a_{2j}$.  Convince yourself how $b_1$ is $a_2$, $b_2$ is $a_4$, etc... Does that help at all?